# Data from API not being outputted | React, Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm fetching data from an API and I'm using React and Redux to do so. I am successfully getting data from the API.
Here's the console.log with the output:

`console.log(this.props.customer.data)`
 [image]

But I can't get it to display in my React app. I bet my problem is really basic, but I really don't understand why this is not working.

I tried doing this inside of `return`:

```
{this.props.customer.data.map(customers => <p>{customers.name}</p>)}
```

But I'm only getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

If anyone know why this is happening, please let me know! Thanks!

(I know that I should not have my props in singular, because it represents multiple customers..)

Comment: Is it failing when first trying to render? Do you have a default value for `this.props.customer.data`?

Comment: What do you mean with default value?

Comment: I mean that the initial state for `customer.data` should be an array.

Comment: Inside my reducer I got this: `export function customer(state = [], action)`

Comment: Is that setting `customer.data` to an array or `customer` to an array?

Comment: its setting customer to an array

Comment: Then there's your problem. As jimmyweb said, you need to initialize it so that `customer.data` is an array.

Comment: I understand. But im uncertain how I should do that hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have an initial value for `customer.data`. You mentioned in another comment that your reducer is setup like this:

```
export function customer(state = [], action) {
  ...
}
```

which is setting `customer` to an array. Instead, do something like this in your reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  data: [] // <-- Default value for customer.data is an empty array
};

export function customer(state = initialState, action) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: The funny part is that I had that before, but I removed it for some reason............. Thanks Mike!

Comment: @MartinNordström Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 3):

You're basically trying to iterate over undefined/null object. Good practice is to set arrays initial state in redux store to an empty array. Having that you don't have to add additional checks in your component to check if array actually exists. `Array.prototype.map` just won't iterate over an empty array and won't render anything. Make sure you set initial state of `customer.data` to an empty array in your reducer.

Comment: I have this in my reducer: `export function customer(state = [], action)`

Answer (score 2):

If you fetch data from API, you have no data in initial rendering, so you should try something like this:

```
    {this.props.customer.data ? this.props.customer.data.map(customers => 
      <p>
        {customers.name}
      </p>) : null}
```